# focus-visible not working in some links after change the style to the whole html

Tags: html, css

I am working on an old HTML that isn't semantic and after inserting the style in focus-visible to the whole HTML, the focus style stops working when the user press tab on the keyboard if there is a `<div>` inside the anchor tag but if I leave the default style from the browser it works.

I would like to understand why this happens? Is possible to fix it using only CSS without use any tabIndex or change the code to be more semantic.

Pseudo code example:

```css
*:focus-visible {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click here and press tab</h2>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="/xxxx"><div><span></span>link x</div></a>
  <a href="/yyyy"><div><span></span>link y</div></a>
  <a href="/zzzzz"><div><span></span>link z</div></a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">focus working</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you apply `display: inline-block` to the links, it appears to work fine (tested in Chrome.)

Comment: @CBroe the problem with the display inline-block it will broken the style from client's website. But your idea maybe can help someone. Do you know why the default style from the browser works if I skip the changes?

Comment: Does display: block ruin things? It also has the effect of showing the outline on focus-visible.

Comment: @AHaworth unfortunately it does :/ they have a display: flex inside and it makes the focus visible not work properly as well. But the interesting thing is the default focus visible from the browser works with it.